# Вывод вычесления из sqlite запроса в java

Tags: java, sqlite

```
public void bs()throws SQLException{


    String sql="SELECT \n" +
        "    CAST((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s',  users.data))/(60 * 60 * 24) AS TEXT) || ' д ' || \n" +
        "    CAST(((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s',  users.data)) % (60 * 60 * 24))/(60 * 60) AS TEXT) || ' ч ' || \n" +
        "    CAST((((strftime('%s', 'now','localtime') - strftime('%s',  users.data)) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60))/60 AS TEXT) || ' м ' \n" +
        "from users where userId= " + id + "");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        stmt=con.createStatement();
        res=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println( ?);
```

как теперь вытащить в систем аут результат этого запроса в том виде как он в sqlite выводится по типу : 2д  14 ч 34м

Comment: проблема в том ,что все методы класа Resultset выводят конкретный столбец,а как вывести результат вычитая одного значения из другого,Которое не записывается в базу данных вот в чем вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос 
res.getString(1) 
вернул мне точто такое же значение как и в визуальном редакторе SQLite